# ADFS: Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request

Tags: windows, active-directory, adfs

I am trying to configure a new ADFS server on my AD, and, after install it, when i try to start the adfssrv service, i can't, and i receive this error:

> Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the
> control request.

How can i do to solve this issue?
Thank so much.

Comment: Check the relevant event log (EventViewer -> Applications and Services -> ADFS -> Admin), it should contain more details about the underlying exception that was thrown on startup